# How to call oracle function in JPA EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I can't call oracle function in my java application.
I have the following oracle function:

```
FUNCTION GetClientAcc(
  client_id in integer,
  call_date in date default null
) RETURN ACC_TBL;

TYPE ACC_TBL IS REF CURSOR RETURN ACC_REC;

TYPE ACC_REC IS RECORD (
 client_id      NUMBER,   
 acc_id         NUMBER,
 acc_num        VARCHAR2(25),     
 order_data     CLOB
);
```

And I try to call it in java application:

```
 StoredFunctionCall functionCall = new StoredFunctionCall();
    functionCall.setProcedureName("GetClientAcc");
    functionCall.addNamedArgument("client_id");
    functionCall.addNamedArgument("call_date");
    functionCall.setResult("ACC_TBL");

    ReadAllQuery query = new ReadAllQuery();
    query.setReferenceClass(AccountInfo.class);
    query.setCall(functionCall);
    query.addArgument("client_id");
    query.addArgument("call_date");
    List<Object> args= new ArrayList<>();
    args.add(10);
    args.add(new Date());
    JpaEntityManager jpaEntityManager = JpaHelper.getEntityManager(emNt);
    Session session = jpaEntityManager.getActiveSession();
    List<AccountInfo> result =                   (List<AccountInfo>)session.executeQuery(query, args);
```

I do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: and it does "something" when you call it and you don't share that with people here. So nobody here will understand "why it does not work" because they have no information. And you also have the log.